# Volume Absorption makes my water completely black?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I'm working on Grant Abbitt's low-poly sea shack tutorial. I have my water, and I wanted to try and add some volume absorption to it to see what it would look like. However, whenever I try to add the volume absorption node, my water turns completely black, and doesn't change at all regardless of what settings I change.

Can anyone help me out?

[image]

No Volume Absorption:
[image]

Volume Absorption:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Usually the default value of 1.0 on volume nodes is way too high.

Use a much lower value for the density. This is the volume absorption set at 0.001

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think that it could go below 1.0, ha... Alright thanks! This was helpful. Also, how/why is everything in your screenshot purple? Is that a particular view type to help see the difference?

Also, the reason I didn't know it could go below 1.0 was because in the BlenderGuru donut tutorial, I had basic water and had to set it to some crazy high value like 500 or so.

Comment: it is pink because the file is missing the images used as textures, you didn't pack them so they are not part of the file.

Comment: Oh? .. I clicked the "Pack all into .blend" button... Hm.